# How to return results from 2 SQL Server tables where one column in common

Tags: sql-server, join

I've been reading for about 2 hours this afternoon and trying different things to get the results that I need but so far have failed.

Table: Schedule

- ScheduleID NOT NULL
- EmployeeID NOT NULL
- ItemDate NOT NULL

Table: Holidays

- HolidayID NOT NULL
- EmployeeID NOT NULL
- ItemDate NOT NULL

I want to return a result set that has all of the Schedule dates and all of the Holiday dates for a given EmployeeID

Sample data:

Schedule:

```
ScheduleID    EmployeeID    ItemDate
------------------------------------
     1             1        1/1/2021 
     2             1        3/1/2021
```

Holiday:

```
HolidayID    EmployeeID    ItemDate 
-----------------------------------
    1             1        2/1/2021
```

Should return the following result set

```
ScheduleID 1 EmployeeID 1 ItemDate 1/1/2021  
HolidayID 1 EmployeeID 1 ItemDate 2/1/2021  
ScheduleID 2 EmployeeID 1 ItemDate 3/1/2021
```

I have tried all sorts of joins, inner, outer, right, left but I can't seem to find any scenario that works for what I want.

I'm happy to have NULL values for any of the columns in the returned result set as I can handle this in the code.

The closest I've got is this but I need to have the HolidayID (even if NULL) and/or the ScheduleID (even if NULL) in the results.

```
SELECT ScheduleID, HolidayID, EmployeeID, ItemDate  
FROM Schedule  
FULL OUTER JOIN Holiday ON Holiday.EmployeeID = Schedule.EmployeeID  
ORDER BY ItemDate  
WHERE EmployeeID = 1
```

Thanks

Comment: Looks like there is Employee table as well due to EmployeeID in the tables.  Looks like you may want/need to use Employee as the main table (first one in your joins) and join from Employee to the other 2 using LEFT JOINS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to do this is with a UNION operator: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

A union will append multiple select statements into one table result. A requirement for a union is the columns must be in order and the same data type. I am putting the results into a WITH clause. This allows you to quickly search for a specific employee ID. If you did not do this you would need two where clauses within the union.

```
    WITH Dates AS (
        SELECT ScheduleID, EmployeeID, ItemDate
        FROM Schedule
        UNION
        SELECT HolidayID, EmployeeID, ItemDate
        FROM Holiday
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM Dates
    WHERE EmployeeID = 1
```

Comment: Thanks Jerrit, that worked perfectly! Just a quick follow-up. If I want to add in other columns to the first SELECT statement which aren't included in the second UNION SELECT statement, I've just put NULLs there. It's working fine but wanted to check whether this was the correct way to do it? I simplified the table layout for the sake of the question, there are a few more columns I need from the Schedule table and the Holiday table which aren't on the other table but I'm happy to get NULL results in those columns in my results as I can filter this in the code.

Comment: Hi Sains, yes that is correct. If you run into a scenario where the columns do not match exactly you can provide a empty string '' or a NULL in the other select statements. The first table to appear in a UNION is considered authoritative for anything below it (This includes the name + data type used). Generally UNIONS are only useful if you are dealing with similar data from multiple sources. I would try to normalize your data and combine them into the same column when possible to reduce the amount of empty columns. If you are only dealing with a few then it is not a big deal.